# MySQL order by field plus field

Tags: mysql, sorting, field

I have a table

```
id   type       left    right 
1    featured   1       2 
2    default    3       1 
3    default    5       2 
4    default    2       7 
5    featured   3       4 
6    featured   3       2 
7    day        1       3
8    default    12      42
```

I need output five id where `type != day` and sort it by `sum(left + right)` and sort it by featured, default

First, need all the featured type `ORDERING by sum(left + right)`, than with `type = dafule ordering by sum(left + right) LIMIT 5`

What I want to get:

```
5, 6, 1, 8, 4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Were you specific in wanting the results as a single string of IDs qualified in the order, or was the result set or rows ok.  I understand the order basis of the return set though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort by "Featured" coming first is the IF() in the order by... if the type is "featured", then use 1 as the sort basis, otherwise, use 2.  Since you only have featured and default available (restricting "day" entries).  Otherwise, that would be changed to a CASE/WHEN construct to account for other types

```
select
      yt.id,
      yt.type,
      yt.left + yt.right as LeftPlusRight
   from 
      YourTable yt
   where
      yt.type <> 'day'
   order by
      if( yt.type = 'featured', 1, 2 ),
      LeftPlusRight  DESC
   limit 5
```

Answer (score 1):

With the expected result:

> 5, 6, 1, 8, 4

you actually want to sort the id by `type` desc, then by `sum` of `left` and `right` desc, so the following query may fulfill your need:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    tlr
WHERE
    `type`!='day'
ORDER BY 
    `type` DESC, `left`+`right` DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

it works like this:

```
mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > select * from tlr;
+----+----------+------+-------+
| id | type     | left | right |
+----+----------+------+-------+
|  1 | featured |    1 |     2 |
|  2 | default  |    3 |     1 |
|  3 | default  |    5 |     2 |
|  4 | default  |    2 |     7 |
|  5 | featured |    3 |     4 |
|  6 | featured |    3 |     2 |
|  7 | day      |    1 |     3 |
|  8 | default  |   12 |    42 |
+----+----------+------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > select id from tlr where `type`!='day' order by type desc, `left`+`right` desc limit 5;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  1 |
|  8 |
|  4 |
+----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
from your_table
where `type` != 'day'
order by `type`, sum(left + right)
group by `type`    
limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     ID
FROM 
     yourTable
WHERE 
     type <> 'day'
ORDER BY (type = 'featured') DESC, (`left` + `right`) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The above query give you the right result i think.